# How to handle errors from ndb.put_multi

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The documentation for GAE's `ndp.put_multi` is severely lacking. [NDB Entities and Keys - Python — Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#multiple) shows that it returns a list of keys (`list_of_keys = ndb.put_multi(list_of_entities)`), but it says nothing about failures. [NDB Functions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/functions) doesn't provide much more information.

Spelunking through the code (below), shows me that, at least for now, `put_multi` just aggregates the `Future.get_result()`s returned from the async method, which itself delegates to the entities' `put` code. Now, the [docs for the NDB Future Class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/futureclass#Future_get_result) indicate that a result will be returned or else an exception will be raised. I've been told, however, that the result will be `None` if a particular `put` failed (I can't find any authoritative documentation to that effect, but if it's anything like [`db.get`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#get) then that would make sense).

[image: the code]

So all of this boils down to some questions I can't find the answers to:

1. Clearly, the return value is a list - is it a list with some elements possibly None? Or are exceptions used instead?
2. When there is an error, what should be re-put? Can all entities be re-put (idempotent), or only those whose return value are `None` (if that's even how errors are communicated)?
3. How common are errors (One answer: [1/3000](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors))? Do they show up in logs (because I haven't seen any)? Is there a way to reliably simulate an error for testing?

[Usage of the function in an open source library](https://code.openhub.net/file?fid=O28IfxtounwNPG8Ur-DOe-gcu5U&cid=K65J2-PpO44&s=ndb.put_multi&fp=282590&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0) implies that the operation is idempotent, but that's about it. ([Other usages don't even bother checking the return value or catching exceptions](http://nullege.com/codes/search/google.appengine.ext.ndb.put_multi).)

[Handling Datastore Errors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/handling_datastore_errors) makes no mention of anything but exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with your reading of the code: `put_multi()` reacts to an error the same way `put_async().get_result()` does.  If `put()` would raise an exception, `put_multi()` will also, and will be unhelpful about which of the multiple calls failed.  I'm not aware of a circumstance where `put_multi()` would return `None` for some entries in the key list.

You can re-put entities that have been put, assuming no other user has updated those entities since the last put attempt.  Entities that are created with system-generated IDs have their in-memory keys updated, so re-putting these would overwrite the existing entities and not create new ones.  I wouldn't call it idempotent exactly because the retry would overwrite any updates to those entities made by other processes.

Of course, if you need more control over the result, you can perform this update in a transaction, though all entities would need to be in the same entity group for this to work with a primitive transaction.  (Cross-group transactions support up to five distinct entity groups.)  A failure during a transaction would ensure that none of the entities are created or updated if any of the attempts fail.

I don't know a general error rate for update failures.  Such failures are most likely to include contention errors or "hot tablets" (too many updates to nearby records in too short a time, resulting in a timeout), which would depend on app behavior.  All such errors are reported by the API as exceptions.

The easiest way to test error handling call paths would be to wrap the `Model` class and override the methods with a test mode behavior.  You could get fancier and dig into the stub API used by `testbed`, which may have a way to hook into low-level calls and simulate errors. (I don't think this is a feature of `testbed` directly but you could use a similar technique.)